# How to covert to varchar column to date time where column is in mixed mode

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, type-conversion

I have a column in sql server 2012. The column has date stored in varchar. The date data looks like this: dd/mm/yyyy

However there is a catch. The data that is within the column is in refusing to convert. Details investigation reveals that some are convertible to date mode and others are not (may be due to date stored as text mode). I tried to upload the data in date format. But it is also refusing to do so.

Sample Data:

```
Original    Validation Check
10/03/1974  3/10/1974
02/02/1990  2/2/1990
16/05/1988  NULL
```

What should I do?

PS: Found out that some data stored in that column is not in date format, so it was refusing to convert. Thanks to Mr. @Digvijay Verma, he correctly predicted it and with his help I identified the error. Only removing these error and replacing those with valid dates will do the trick.

Regards,
Sadat

Comment: can you please provide us some sample cases of "pass" and "failed"?

Comment: long story short, if you can get the varchar date in yyyy-mm-dd format, conversion should be a lot easier.  dd/mm/yyyy is not very friendly...  i'm assuming that when you say 'upload the data' you have control over this.

Comment: what do you mean by 'convert'?  via a query, or convert the column data type?

Comment: @chappoo: Not sure how I can convert the data to yyyy-mm-dd. Also I need to convert via a query not convert column data type.

Comment: ok, thanks for clarification.  ignore earlier comments.

Comment: Please update your question with all possible different date formats in the column. Also please explain what `Validation check` means.

Comment: @Kaf:  all the data visually looks same. that is: dd-mm-yyyy. But within the column in SQL, some are convertible and others are not. I am presuming that data that are not convertible may be in text string. I can be wrong though.

Comment: You cannot have mixed data types in a single column, they all should be strings or DateTime type. In your case I think they are string type. What is `Validation Check` column in your question? Be clear.

Comment: @Kaf: Validation check is a column that i created to check whether the date column is converted correctly or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your comments, since you are certain about the string format (`dd/mm/yyyy`) you have in the column, I suspect your **problem could be due to a leading/trailing space**.

Try this with `Ltrim()`, `Rtrim()` and `Isdate()` functions. If you get any date `01/01/1900` (Assuming this date is not in your field) in the convertedDate field, you are having more troubles than spaces:

```
Select Original,
       Case when IsDate(Ltrim(Rtrim(Original))) = 1
            then Convert(date, Ltrim(Rtrim(Original)), 103)
            else Convert(date, '19000101', 112) --date in yyyymmdd format
       End ConvertedDate,
From yourTable
```

Comment: you are absolutely correct. I had a chat with Sadat. And we figured out 5 invalid records using IsDate check
0/0/1  0 
01/0/1  0 
30/0/1   0 
43589  0 
23761  0

Comment: @DigvijayVerma, Okay if the issue has been identified next step would be to clear up the data. He could use `WHERE IsDate(Ltrim(Rtrim(Original))) = 1` filter to isolate them and replace with some proper dates. **Date should never be stored as a string.**

Answer (score 2):

The date format you have in the db (dd/mm/yyyy) is 103.

So you should try

```
SELECT convert(datetime, '31/10/2013', 103)
```

As per your clarifications, it seems you need the data in yyyy-mm-dd format. so please try below.

```
SELECT convert(varchar(max),(convert(datetime, '31/10/2013', 103)), 120)
```

Comment: It do not works. Says "conversation failed". This is due to mix mode of data stored in the column.

Comment: I believe this is due to NULL values.
Can you please check for nulls in where clause?

Comment: Btw, what is mixed mode of data here?? sorry I really didn't get you on this. do you have 'dd/mm/yyyy' and other formats also???

Comment: It is not that the data in other formats, they visually look same i.e. dd/mm/yyyy. But within the column some in date format and other are as text format.

Comment: I tried with above code. But it shows following error: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40314/discussion-between-digvijay-verma-and-sadat-mainuddin)

Answer (score 1):

If the dates are in dd/mm/yyyy format, try

```
set dateformat dmy
select try_convert(datetime,date_col) from table
```

All other formats will be shown as NULL

Comment: it is like this, I want to convert whole data column to date format.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
SELECT Original,
       case when left(Original,2) > 12 then convert(datetime, Original, 103)
            else convert(datetime, Original, 101) 
       end
from t1
```

[Here a small demo on SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e1c87/11)

Comment: How do you distinguish `11/12/2012` is 11th of december or 12th of November? So if the first two digits > 12 how do you decide if it is `MM` or `dd`? How about if it is `yyyy-MM-dd` format?

Comment: @mucio: I used above code but it shows following error: Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '0/' to data type int.

Comment: when you deal with bad data quality like in this case the best thing is to ask for better data, otherwise the only thing you can do is to try to convert as you can. Sadat asked to convert all the data, the best option would be convert where is possible and put the bad formatted date in a different table to send them back to the source system (if possible, otherwise deal with that). To answer your question: with the date 10-12-13 how you decide which is dd, mm or yy? Correct data format is to avoid this kind of ambiguity, if data quality is bad, nobody can pretend miracles

Comment: @SadatMainuddin: I don't think anyone can provide you an answer without knowing all different types of date formats you having in the column. I think you need to update the question and provide more details.

Comment: @Kaf: It should be 12th of November and all of the data shows same format that is: dd-mm-yyyy. However within the data some rows are in text string.

Comment: the truth is that all the data are in text format, some of them are dd-mm-yyyy, some are yyyy-mm-dd or something else. You can use CASEs to try to intercept all the possible formats, not sure if this is really possible

Comment: @mucio: all the data visually looks same. that is: dd-mm-yyyy. But within the column in SQL, some are convertible and others are not. I am presuming that data that are not convertible may be in text string. I can be wrong though.

Comment: So, unless I'm reading this wrong, you're stating that 11/12/2012 should be 12th November?  That's mm/dd/yyyy, not dd/mm/yyyy.  In the question, you clearly state that all dates are in format dd/mm/yyyy.  Which one is it?  Please be clear.

Comment: @chappoo: Sorry, It should be 11th of December :S and it should be dd/mm/yyyy